# I have some problems when typing the react-native start command 'cannot find module 'metro-resolver'

Tags: react-native

> D:\Alief\Kelas-12\KK4-B\react_native_crud>react-native start error

Below is the error what i am getting after running the above command,

```
Cannot find module 'metro-resolver'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for
   more details. Error: Cannot find module 'metro-resolver' at
   Function.Module._resolveFilename
   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15) at Function.Module._load
   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25) at Module.require
   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17) at require
   (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18) at Object.<anonymous>
   (D:\Alief\Kelas-12\KK4-B\react_native_crud\node_modules\metro-
   core\src\errors\PackageResolutionError.js:12:18) at Module._compile
   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30) at
   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32) at
   tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12) at
   Function.Module._load
   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)emphasized text
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing the dependency  metro-resolver?

Open cmd in your react-native project's folder and run command

`npm i metro-resolver` & `npm install`.

if using yarn, 
`yarn add metro-resolver`
&
`yarn install`

`npm i metro-resolver`  will install "metro-resolver" and `npm install` will install all the required dependencies mentioned in your `package.json` .

You can  run `npm install` only but in-case metro-resolver is not on your package.json so you'll have to download it by name `npm install metro-resolver` otherwise `npm install` is enough .